# React custom use hook creates loop of errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a reusable IntersectionObserver use hook in ReactJS 18.
I have a component like:

```
import { useObserver } from '../../utils/useObserver'
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent(){
    const section = useRef(null)

    const disconnect = false; // disconnect after intersection
    const isIntersecting = useObserver(section, {
        root: null,
        threshold: 0,
        rootMargin: .6
    }, disconnect);

    // OBSERVER
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isIntersecting) {
            console.log('in')
        }else{
            console.log('out')
        }
    },[isIntersecting])

    return(
        <section ref={section}></section>
    )
}
```

in utils I have my **useObserver.js** :

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export function useObserver(ref, options = {}, forward = true) {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null)
  const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false)
  const observer = useRef(null)

  const cleanOb = () => {
    if (observer.current) {
      observer.current.disconnect()
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setElement(ref.current)
  }, [ref])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!element) return
    cleanOb()
    const ob = (observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        const isElementIntersecting = entry.isIntersecting
        if (!forward) {
          setIsIntersecting(isElementIntersecting)
        } else if (forward && !isIntersecting && isElementIntersecting) {
          setIsIntersecting(isElementIntersecting)
          cleanOb()
        }
      },
      { ...options }
    ))
    ob.observe(element)
    return () => {
      cleanOb()
    }
  }, [element, options])

  return isIntersecting
}
```

why does it make the web app crash like this? sometimes it throws an infinite number of errors in the browser console like "commitHookEffectListMount" and more, sometimes nothing just blocks at the start.

If from the custom hook I comment everything and `return true;` the `useEffect` in my component correctly console logs 'in' once the app starts, and it doesn't crash.

Comment: Have you tried memoizing `options` with `useMemo()`

Comment: This might help you https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-intersection-observer

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting an infinite loop, but at least part of the issue may be that your dependency list for your setElement useEffect is on the ref itself, which is stable and mutable (one reason people use refs is to get around things that are a pain when your data is immutable), so that is only ever going to run once and will never clean up.

Comment: Also, if you don't provide options from outside, your options object will be a new reference on every render, causing that logic to run against what's likely an old ref. Try providing stable options from the calling code and see if that fixes the infinite loop.